# Pause and resume file upload with dotnet core and javascript

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

How to pause and resume file upload with dotnet core and javascript where in frontend I would have pause button to pause the file upload and resume it

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description, but that doesn't tell us what _problem_ you're having. What have you tried, and what troubles did you encounter? Please [edit] your post to include a [valid question](/help/how-to-ask) that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know what is [on-topic](/help/on-topic); asking us to write the program for you, suggestions, and external links are off-topic.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cancel, Abort and Retry individual file upload with ResumableJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27140184/cancel-abort-and-retry-individual-file-upload-with-resumablejs)

Answer (score 1):

The ResumableJS libray Ramil mentioned is greate, and I also search a good sample code for you, so that you can quickly integrate into your project.

> This library is explicitly designed for modern browsers supporting advanced HTML5 file features, and the motivation has been to provide stable and resumable support for large files (allowing uploads of several GB files through HTTP in a predictable fashion).

[Chunked file uploading to a .NET Core 3.1 API server](https://github.com/Jason446620/Arad.ChunkedUpload)

[image]